# Linq for Conditionally Flattening a List of Strings with Different Depth

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of objects, containing a string, **OR** a list of strings. I'm trying to extract a list of "flattened" strings.  I have a solution, but I'm trying to find a better way.

Here are the simple steps to create the input:

```
class Foo
{
    public bool IsArray { get; set; }
    public object Values { get; set; }
} //...    

var innerList = new List<string> {"Inner111", "Inner222"}

var fooList = new List<Foo>();
fooList.Add(new Foo { IsArray = false, Values = "simpleVaue" });
fooList.Add(new Foo { IsArray = false, Values = innerList });
```

**My desired outcome**:

```
["simpleVale","Inner111","Inner222"]
```

I've tried a few different Linq methods, SelectMany, Aggregate,Select ...

```
var outputListWithWastefulListCreation = 
fooList.SelectMany<Foo, string>(z =>
{
    if (!z.IsArray)
    {
        var wastefulList = new List<string> {z.Values.ToString()};
        return wastefulList;
    }
    var listObject = (IEnumerable<string>) z.Values;
    return listObject;
});
```

**Again, my desired outcome**:

```
["simpleVale","Inner111","Inner222"]
```

**I'm sure there must be a better way?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try converting single value into a collection within `SelectMany`:

```
 var result = fooList
   .SelectMany(item => item.IsArray
      ? item.Values as List<String>
      : new List<String>() {item.Values as String});
```

Another, and, IMHO, a better possibility is to implement `IEnumerable<String> GetValues()' method in the`foo` class:

```
class Foo
{
    public bool IsArray { get; set; }
    public object Values { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<String> GetValues() 
    {
      if (null == values)
          yield break;

      List<String> list = Values as List<String>;

      if (list != null)
          foreach (var item in list)
              yield return item;
      else
          yield return Values as String;
    }
}
```

and so you can put just

```
var result = fooList
   .SelectMany(item => item.GetValues());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
fooList.SelectMany<Foo, string>(z => z.IsArray ? ((List<string>) z.Values) : new List<string>() {(string) z.Values});
```

But the first thing to do - is to think whether your Foo class design is ok or you can change it (with probably two different classes for one string and the list) to avoid such tricky problems.